# Delete duplicates from a snowflake table without creating a new table

Tags: duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table 'TEST' as below.

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST (
  HASH VARCHAR,
  COL1 VARCHAR,
  COL2 VARCHAR,
  COL3 VARCHAR
);    

INSERT INTO TEST values ('cpdfer0', 'abc', 'xyz', 'I');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('sdfghj7', 'bnm', 'xyz', 'J');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('cpdfer0', 'abc', 'xyz', 'K');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('acvfgt9', 'xyz', 'bnm', 'K');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('zp3fert', 'cbc', 'lyz', 'M');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('acvfgt9', 'xyz', 'bnm', 'N');
```

I want to delete duplicate rows from TEST table on column 'HASH' (without creating a new table). I tried below query but it does not work. What is wrong with my query?

```
DELETE FROM TEST WHERE HASH NOT IN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
      SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HASH ORDER BY HASH) AS rbn
      FROM TEST
  )
  WHERE rbn = 1);
```

Expected rows after dropping duplicates from TEST

[image]

Comment: I don't want to include any other columns other than hash.

Comment: Does `select hash, min(col1),min(col2),min(col3) from old_table group by hash` give you what you need in terms of desired output?

Comment: deleting from a table, and creating a new table are the same operation, if you ignore the fact messing with permissions and timetravel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that would work:

```
DELETE FROM test 
WHERE hash||col1||col2||col3 IN (
    SELECT hash||col1||col2||col3 FROM (
        SELECT hash, col1, col2, col3, 
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY hash ORDER BY hash, col1, col2, col3) rbn 
        FROM test
    ) WHERE rbn > 1
);
```

The reason that I'm using `hash||col1||col2||col3` instead of just `hash` is that I need to identify the exact row that I want to delete. If I used just `hash` to identify the rows that I want to delete, it would delete all rows with that `hash`. Note also that this code works correctly when each row for the same `hash` is different (like in your sample data, COL3 is different). If there were any exactly duplicate rows, it would delete all of them.

Comment: I dont want to include col1,col2,col3. I tried to tweak your code as below, but it is completely dropping cpdfer0 and acvfgt9 hash    DELETE FROM test 
WHERE hash IN (
    SELECT hash FROM (
        SELECT *, 
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY hash ORDER BY hash) rbn 
        FROM test
    ) WHERE rbn > 1
);

Comment: Like I said in my explanation, you can't delete just by specifying hash, it will delete all records with that hash.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this,

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008EJgemSAD/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST (
  HASH1 VARCHAR,
  COL1 VARCHAR,
  COL2 VARCHAR,
  COL3 VARCHAR
);    

INSERT INTO TEST values ('cpdfer0', 'abc', 'xyz', 'I');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('sdfghj7', 'bnm', 'xyz', 'J');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('cpdfer0', 'abc', 'xyz', 'K');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('acvfgt9', 'xyz', 'bnm', 'K');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('zp3fert', 'cbc', 'lyz', 'M');
INSERT INTO TEST values ('acvfgt9', 'xyz', 'bnm', 'N');


select * from test order by hash;

alter table test add id varchar(100);
update test  set id = UUID_STRING();


delete from test
 where id in (select id from ( SELECT t.* ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HASH1 ORDER BY HASH1) AS rbn
                       from test t)
              where rbn > 1);

alter table test drop id;

DELETE FROM  test
WHERE hash1 NOT IN
(
    SELECT MIN(hash1)
    FROM test
    GROUP BY hash1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is an interesting problem and have tried to get sort-of twisty work-around,
given the fact Snowflake do not have any in-build pseudo columns in tables like rowid
(as offered in other databases).

Idea used - Merge:

Construct an in-line view/subquery that will only have duplicate rows
and that too just two records for each duplicate entry.

Now, change this sub-query set as - leaving one record intact (or original) and
modify the second record to add some random char/string to the main duplicate column
making it different or distinct from the original record.
Once we have the above set (inline view/query) then use the same to MERGE.
Merge against this inline view to DELETE on existing/similar records and
insert back the ones that we have slightly modified making them different
from the original. Also, while re-inserting we take-off what was added, to
change it back as the original record.

I tested on limited data-set, not exactly sure how this would behave on a large or huge data-set. Also this is removing second row from the duplicate set, look into adjusting clause 'rn = 2', as needed. Main idea I tried was to remove without using pseudo-column.

Post back in case anyone has suggestions or find it not working.

Current state for the table -

```
select * from test_hash;
+---------+------+------+------+
| HASH    | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
|---------+------+------+------|
| cpdfer0 | abc  | xyz  | I    |
| sdfghj7 | bnm  | xyz  | J    |
| cpdfer0 | abc  | xyz  | K    |
| acvfgt9 | xyz  | bnm  | K    |
| zp3fert | cbc  | lyz  | M    |
| acvfgt9 | xyz  | bnm  | N    |
+---------+------+------+------+
```

## Main query used to remove duplicates

```
merge into TEST_HASH using
(
select case when rn=1 then HASH else HASH||'|randomstr' end HASH ,
col1,col2,col3
from (
select *,row_number() 
over (partition by hash order by HASH) rn 
from (select *,count(HASH) 
over (partition by HASH order by HASH) cnt 
from TEST_HASH qualify cnt>1) qualify rn<3
)
) d
on TEST_HASH.HASH = d.HASH
when matched then delete
when not matched then insert (HASH,col1,col2,col3) 
values (substr(d.hash,1,position('|',d.hash)-1),d.col1,d.col2,d.col3);
```

State of the table after execution of remove duplicates -

```
select * from test_hash;
+---------+------+------+------+
| HASH    | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
|---------+------+------+------|
| acvfgt9 | xyz  | bnm  | K    |
| cpdfer0 | abc  | xyz  | I    |
| sdfghj7 | bnm  | xyz  | J    |
| zp3fert | cbc  | lyz  | M    |
+---------+------+------+------+
```